# need htaccess rule for reading images from different source

Tags: .htaccess

i have been trying to get work a htaccess rule for the below but i cannot figure it out.

/theimages/100/150/IMAGE-FOLDER-image.jpg

should read from :

/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=IMAGE/FOLDER/image.jpg&ae=1&w=100&h=150

any help appreciated 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^theimages/([^/]+)/?$ phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^theimages/(\d+)/(\d+)/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-.]+\.jpg)$ phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=$3/$4/$5&ae=1&w=$1&h=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: /theimages/asdsadasdasdasdassasda
should read from :

/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=asdsadasdasdasdassasda

Comment: hi there , any chance you would look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092640/using-htaccess-read-image-from-other-domain