# using htaccess read image from other domain

Tags: .htaccess

is there any way in htaccess to convert :

theimages/library/tour_preview/Blarney-Castle_7.jpg?f=png&w=250&h=190&far=0

to :

phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://example.com/library/tour_preview/Blarney-Castle_7.jpg&f=png&w=250&h=190&far=0

so basically :
1) the 'theimages' is replaced by phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://example.com

2) and the ? in the original link will be replaced by a &

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^theimages/(.+)/?$ phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://example.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA,NE]
```